# Using webpack and react to develop google extensions, how to do hot reload?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, webpack-dev-server

I am using below configuration to develop google extension, and I use `webpack-dev-server` to do hot reload, but when I refresh the extension, I always get an error: **Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'".**. By the way, when I build the project it works normal.
Please tell me how to fix it, or how to do hot reload. thanks.

`webpack.config.ts`

```js
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require("fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    index: "./extension/index.tsx",
    background: "./extension/background.ts",
  },
  output: {
    filename: "[name].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    clean: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: "ts-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "postcss-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./assets/index.html",
      filename: "index.html",
      chunks: ["index"],
    }),
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: "extension/manifest.json", to: "[name][ext]" },
        { from: "assets/images", to: "images/" },
      ],
    }),
    new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin(),
  ],
  devServer: {
    devMiddleware: {
      writeToDisk: true,
    },
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        extractComments: false,
      }),
    ],
  },
};
```

`manifest.json`

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Quick Note",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "/images/get_started16.png",
      "32": "/images/get_started32.png",
      "48": "/images/get_started48.png",
      "128": "/images/get_started128.png"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "/images/get_started16.png",
    "32": "/images/get_started32.png",
    "48": "/images/get_started48.png",
    "128": "/images/get_started128.png"
  }
}
```

`package.json`

```json
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack server --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "lint": "lint-staged",
    "prepare": "husky install"
  },
```

Answer (score -1):

1. You have to add

`module.exports = { configureWebpack: { devtool: 'source-map', },`

2. Add your nodejs server and port to MV3  for example,

`"content_security_policy": { "extension_pages": " connect-src ws://localhost:8000/" },`
try step one
then, step two

Comment: `configureWebpack` is not a valid WebPack Configuration option.